# Why did the system allow this short answer (< 30 characters) to be posted?

Tags: bug, answers, low-quality-posts, character-limit

I know about invisible CSS characters and invisible Unicode characters. But this is different.

I recently saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66019566/12708583) ([screenshot in case it gets deleted or edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHJdS.png)), and I wanted to edit it. Once I was done, this is what I see:

[image: Error that prevents the edits states, "Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 22."]

When I remove the quotations around the function `timeframe.period`, this is what I see:

[image: Error that prevents the edits states, "Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 21."]

With the quotations however, it works as normal.

What is going on here? The quotations can't be worth 9 characters!

Comment: The logic for that is on the backend, not on the frontend - that error comes back from a network request, so there's no easy way to determine the cause

Comment: It's also weird that deleting 2 characters only reduced the total character count by one.

Comment: Maybe some HTML shenanigans with the quotes being parsed as `&quot;` by the validator or something like that?

Comment: Maybe there was a signature that got stripped out automatically but still counted toward the character limit? I'm not sure. I would have thought that an answer this short would have been automatically converted to a comment.

Comment: @Cody Gray: The automatic comment "conversion" only happens when the submission includes a Q&A link.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thanks, @BoltClock; I'd forgotten that restriction.

Comment: @Cody Gray: You likely forgot it because it doesn't even make sense as a rule for this feature.